# Pictures have disappeared from Google Images

Tags: google, google-image-search

All my images have disappeared from Google Images and can't understand why.  There's no email from google saying why, i.e. copyright, other issues.  Has there been an update to the search engine yesterday or has anyone else had problems?  All the webpages are there and they come up.  Some images do come up, for example, when you search for Kornephoros in text search, my image appears.  Google Webmaster tools says it has indexed 2479 out of 3391 images but none come up,  I checked the logs and they're still being visited by Google Image Bot.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the [Manual Actions report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604824?hl=en)?

Comment: It also helps to know your Google region. Are you using alt tags on your images? Has your site undergone any recent changes? Have you checked your backlink profile? There's a broad number of variables in play.

Comment: Thanks Dan for the link, didn't spot it earlier in WMT, there is a manual action i need to do it would seem, done it and submitted a reconsideration.  As for Yhorian, I've rolled back the changes I've done in the past week.  Now to wait and see.

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser No problem. Maybe you can add that to an answer below so it might be helpful to others in the future and the question can be considered closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem there was a Manual Action required as suggested by Dan.  It had also gone through a recent change but doubt that change was the cause.

The reason for all the images to have gone is because Google doesn't like the way I've implemented the HotLink protection scheme.  The scheme similar to what Fansshare.com does to protect against Google from showing just pictures rather than showing the webpage.  There's a lot of comments about this issue on the internet, I'm not the only one.  For example, if you view any picture on google image search and click on 'View Image', you bypass the webpage and just see the picture.  Fansshare.com and my website had got round that way but Google doesn't like the way I do.

http://mistercopyright.org/google-image-search-and-misappropriation-of-copyrighted-images

I've gone back to showing just a hotlinking image rather anything fancy like Fansshare.com.  I made a resubmission and wait to hear back from them.